# Why isn't this on.Click working on my button

Tags: javascript, dom-events

```
///// FORM  ////
var form = document.getElementById("form");
form.setAttribute("style", "position: relative; margin-bottom: 5%;");

var newButton = document.createElement('button');
var newUl = document.createElement('ul');
var newLi = document.createElement('li');
var newInput = document.createElement('input');
form.appendChild(newButton);
newButton.setAttribute("style", "position: absolute; width: 15%; height: 40px; left: 42%; color: #B00000; background-color: white; font-size: 18px; border: 0px; ");
newButton.innerHTML = "Direct Message";
newButton.onClick = function() {
  alert("works");
};
```

Is there something wrong with my selection? just want the on.click to work on my button which is newButton created element.

Comment: Any reason you're **not** posting a MCVE?

Comment: sorry Im somewhat new and didnt know about mcve, sorry about that

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Javascript property names are case-sensitive, it should be `newButton.onclick`.

Or you could move into the modern age and use `addEventListener`.

```
newButton.addEventListener("click", function() {
    alert("works");
});
```

Comment: lol thanks you sir, why is that better than onclick. seems like just more to write for no reason

Comment: It's more general, since you can add multiple listeners with it. It also has an optional argument that allows more flexibility.

Answer (score 0):

Two things:

1. You need to set the "type" attribute of the button to "button";
2. It's "onclick", not "onClick"

The first thing prevents the button from submitting the surrounding `<form>` when it's clicked. The second will correctly set up the event handler.

Comment: ok thank you, what if I do want the form to get submitted into the button function

Comment: @FransB oh well if you *do* want the form to be submitted, then don't set the "type" to "button". Or you can explicitly set the type to "submit" to make things explicit.

Answer (score 0):

this code doesn't work because the syntax is incorrect.

the correct syntax about the event 'click' is below:

```
newButton.onclick = function(){
 alert("works");
};
```

the event is write on the lower case.